# How to get specific attributes of a df that has been grouped

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I'm printing out the frequency of murders in each state in each particular decade. However, I just want to print the state, decade, and it's victim count. What I have right now is that it's printing out all the columns with the same frequencies. How do I change it so that I just have 3 columns, State, Decade, and Victim Count?

I'm currently using the groupby function to group by the state and decade and setting that equal to a variable called count.

```
  xl = pd.ExcelFile('Wyoming.xlsx')
  df = xl.parse('Sheet1')

  df['Decade'] = (df['Year'] // 10) * 10

  counts = df.groupby(['State', 'Decade']).count()

  print(counts)
```

The outcome is printing out all the columns in the file with the same frequencies whereas I just want 3 columns: State Decade Victim Count

[Sample Text File](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5x7zS.png)

Comment: If you have another question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](//stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button, instead of editing your current post.

Comment: Sorry about that. Didn't know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should `reset_index` of the groupby object, and then select the columns from the new dataframe.

Something like

```
xl = pd.ExcelFile('Wyoming.xlsx')
df = xl.parse('Sheet1')

df['Decade'] = (df['Year'] // 10) * 10

counts = df.groupby(['State', 'Decade']).count()
counts = counts.reset_index()[['State', 'Decade','Vistim Count']]
print(counts)
```

Comment: @treatyoself awesome. consider upvoting/accepting [when someone answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: Sorry, I don't have more than 15 reputation to do that as I am a relatively new user of Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

Select the columns that you want:

```
counts = df.loc[:,['State', 'Decade','Vistim Count']].groupby(['State', 'Decade']).count()
```

or

```
print(count.loc[:,['State', 'Decade','Vistim Count']])
```